# Are the width and height dimensions of a kinetic layer or group used in any way?

Tags: kineticjs

After some experimentation with setting the width and height of a kinetic layer I noticed that they appear to have no acertainable effect. For example I can add a shape outside of the width of its containing layer and it will still be drawn on the stage.

It seems a layer expands to include whatever is added to it. Is this correct?

What is the significance of the width and height of a kinetic layer? Are those parameters used in any way?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct.

Kinetic.Layers always fill the stage regardless of the layers width/height setting.

The layers width/height properties exist because they are inherited from Kinetic.Container, but setting a layers width/height has no effect.